# App supported by 0 devices

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, android-manifest, device

I read every post there is on this subject but I still couldn't solve my problem. When I upload my app to the Play Store, it says that there are 0 supported devices. At this point, I have no clue what the problem could be anymore... This is what I tried:

- Check every permission and feature in the manifest and ensure that they are all correct
- Remove all permissions and features entirely, just to see if my app would be compatible with devices then (didn't work)
- I have some jars that my project depends on, so I included them as dependencies in Android Studio

My `manifest` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="..." >

    <!-- Required permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required features -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
    android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name="..."
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_ic"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="..."
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="..."
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="SCAN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="..."
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile files('libs/core-1.51.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/prov-1.51.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/core.jar')
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Native platforms in Developer Console are stated as: junit-4.11.jar, junit-LICENSE.html. Is that normal?

Comment: I am missing the SDK levels in your Manifest. Minimum and target version.

Comment: They are specified in the build.gradle file, which means they are not needed in the manifest

Answer (score 1):

I've seen issues with that in the past, try removing...

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
    android:required="true" />
```